# Stacked barchart with geom_text percentages for only one filling factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my plan: a stacked barchart with outcome 0/1 in 4 age groups.
As `geom_text` labels, I want to show the percentages per age group for `outcome=1`.

First I tried to exclude the `Outcome =="0"` using `geom_text(data=subset(df, outcome=="1")`, but it did not work.

Then I put NA's for the unwanted group percentages, to only show the percentages where `outcome=="1"`. (plot 1)
However, when I add a "%" to the `geom_text` aes with `paste()`, the NA re-appears. (plot 2)

Furthermore, I wish to put the percentages above each bar. With vjust, it has different distances from the top of the bar to the text label.

Any hints how to achieve this?
Many Thanks!

```
# generating data frame
n <- c(450,20,470,30,750,40,650,35)
age_group <- as.factor(c("neonate","neonate", "infant","infant", "child", "child", "adolescent","adolescent"))
outcome <- as.factor(c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1))
percent <- c(NA,20/470, NA, 30/500,NA, 40/790,NA,35/685)

# convert to factors and adjust label order
df <- data.frame(n, age_group, outcome, percent)
df$age_group <- factor(df$age_group, levels=c("neonate","infant","child","adolescent"))
df$outcome <- factor(df$outcome, levels =c("1","0"))

# Plot 1: percentages not in place, missing "%" sign
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=age_group, y=n, fill=outcome)) + 
     geom_bar(stat="identity") +
     geom_text(aes(label=round(percent*100,1)))
p1
```

Plot1:
[image: Plot1]

```
# Plot 2: with percentages, not in place, by adding "%", the NA values appeard
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=age_group, y=n, fill=outcome)) + 
     geom_bar(stat="identity") +
     geom_text(aes(label=paste(round(percent*100,1), "%")))
p2
```

Plot2:
[image: Plot 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# generating data frame
n <- c(450,20,470,30,750,40,650,35)
age_group <- as.factor(c("neonate","neonate", "infant","infant", "child", "child", "adolescent","adolescent"))
outcome <- as.factor(c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1))
percent <- c(NA,20/470, NA, 30/500,NA, 40/790,NA,35/685)

# convert to factors and adjust label order
df <- data.frame(n, age_group, outcome, percent)
df$age_group <- factor(df$age_group, levels=c("neonate","infant","child","adolescent"))
df$outcome <- factor(df$outcome, levels =c("1","0"))


per <- paste(round(percent*100,1),"%")
per[per == "NA %"] <- ""

# Plot 1: percentages not in place, missing "%" sign
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=age_group, y=n, fill=outcome)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_text(
    aes(x = age_group, y = n, label = per, group = outcome),
    position = position_stack(),
    vjust = -0.5, size = 3.5
  )

p1
```

[image]